# Installing PyYAML in docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip, yaml, containers

I am trying to build a container with the yaml package in it.
However when I try to import the package I have the following error:

```
>>> import yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

When I (re)build the Dockerfile I have the following message:

```
Step 14/25 : RUN pip install PyYAML==5.4.1
 ---> Running in 1e94e1d4e7e5
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML==5.4.1 in /root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)
```

For me it means that it's correctly installed.

However, when I do a *pip freeze*, PyYaml is not there.
I also tried to simply reinstall it in the container:

```
pip install PyYaml
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyYaml
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (630 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 630 kB 7.5 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: PyYaml
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.
```

Here are the permissions:

```
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 16 1270 1007 4096 Apr 13 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 1270 1007 4096 Apr 14 16:09 ..
```

I also tried the following solution : https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/291#issuecomment-580608091
by adding the following commands:

```
#In the dockerfile :
ENV PYTHONPATH="/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)"

#or
#In the container
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)
```

But I've still the same error.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y
RUN pip install pip --upgrade pip
RUN pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN pip install imageio
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install Pillow
RUN pip install scipy
RUN pip install wandb --user
RUN pip install PyYAML==5.4.1 
RUN pip install addict
RUN pip install future
RUN pip install lmdb
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install scikit-image
RUN pip install tb-nightly
RUN pip install tqdm
RUN pip install yapf

ENV PYTHONPATH="/home/GAN"
ENV PYTHONPATH="/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)"

WORKDIR /home/
CMD /bin/bash
```

I also tried to use a virtual environment but I get permission errors with wandb.

Comment: `print(sys.path)` in Python?

Comment: ['', '/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)', '/home/GAN/BasicSR-master', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Comment: Resetting `PYTHONPATH` to not include the system paths seems worrisome; does deleting the two `ENV` lines make a difference?

Comment: No it doesn't, when deleting the two ```ENV``` lines it returns an empty ```PYTHONPATH```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Docker are you using? You may want to try upgrading to the latest version. I'm unable to reproduce the error you describe above.

I copy pasted your Dockerfile with no modifications into a local file:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y
RUN pip install pip --upgrade pip
RUN pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN pip install imageio
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install Pillow
RUN pip install scipy
RUN pip install wandb --user
RUN pip install PyYAML==5.4.1
RUN pip install addict
RUN pip install future
RUN pip install lmdb
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install scikit-image
RUN pip install tb-nightly
RUN pip install tqdm
RUN pip install yapf

ENV PYTHONPATH="/home/GAN"
ENV PYTHONPATH="/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.4.1)"

WORKDIR /home/
CMD /bin/bash
```

I then built the image:

```
(wandb-3.6) danielgoldstein@Daniels-MBP d % docker build -t so .
[+] Building 346.0s (27/27) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 835B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2.0s
 => [ 1/23] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:0813df59b3d73a13fc581fd416d7733a2de6540d7e3f7633a1a9aabf9b201548                                                                                                                                                                                                           61.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:0813df59b3d73a13fc581fd416d7733a2de6540d7e3f7633a1a9aabf9b201548                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:0813df59b3d73a13fc581fd416d7733a2de6540d7e3f7633a1a9aabf9b201548 2.36kB / 2.36kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:70aa8983ec5cea7bc143af188b4bdc424fa405184d56dcbdfd9df672ade85249 8.34kB / 8.34kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:fe2971bedd019d952d4458afb1fe4e222ddb810150008c1dee5a068d38bb0e43 2.22kB / 2.22kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => sha256:44718e6d535d365250316b02459f98a1b0fa490158cc53057d18858507504d60 7.83MB / 7.83MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2.0s
 => => sha256:efe9738af0cb2184ee8f3fb3dcb130455385aa428a27d14e1e07a5587ff16e64 10.00MB / 10.00MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                              13.4s
 => => sha256:f37aabde37b87d272286df45e6a3145b0884b72e07e657bf1a2a1e74a92c6172 51.84MB / 51.84MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                              22.0s
 => => sha256:3923d444ed0552ce73ef51fa235f1b45edafdec096abda6abab710637dac7ec6 192.35MB / 192.35MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                            51.3s
 => => extracting sha256:44718e6d535d365250316b02459f98a1b0fa490158cc53057d18858507504d60                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.4s
 => => sha256:1ecef690e281c31d68c3cd0628207e8b02fb0e60575604fc5436404d1007a75e 6.15MB / 6.15MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                29.1s
 => => extracting sha256:efe9738af0cb2184ee8f3fb3dcb130455385aa428a27d14e1e07a5587ff16e64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => => sha256:1c053581d9c97b5cbe226c12f297b53778812e2a19c4ea2c6344aa60f70b9b35 19.19MB / 19.19MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                              29.1s
 => => extracting sha256:f37aabde37b87d272286df45e6a3145b0884b72e07e657bf1a2a1e74a92c6172                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.4s
 => => sha256:83ebd4edf9af1d3be8ae28b17bed10d2da1c5d614563fee3dbf60cf9f94edefd 2.31MB / 2.31MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                30.4s
 => => sha256:81182ea718cf045ec1dd9ca295961b86aefe916d451fc860c0d1a86b9d7540a4 234B / 234B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    29.6s
 => => extracting sha256:3923d444ed0552ce73ef51fa235f1b45edafdec096abda6abab710637dac7ec6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      7.3s
 => => extracting sha256:1ecef690e281c31d68c3cd0628207e8b02fb0e60575604fc5436404d1007a75e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:1c053581d9c97b5cbe226c12f297b53778812e2a19c4ea2c6344aa60f70b9b35                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.9s
 => => extracting sha256:81182ea718cf045ec1dd9ca295961b86aefe916d451fc860c0d1a86b9d7540a4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:83ebd4edf9af1d3be8ae28b17bed10d2da1c5d614563fee3dbf60cf9f94edefd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => [ 2/23] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 4.2s
 => [ 3/23] RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     26.3s
 => [ 4/23] RUN pip install pip --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2.7s
 => [ 5/23] RUN pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html                                                                                                                                                                              162.8s
 => [ 6/23] RUN pip install imageio                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.0s
 => [ 7/23] RUN pip install matplotlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         5.6s
 => [ 8/23] RUN pip install numpy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.7s
 => [ 9/23] RUN pip install opencv-python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     15.3s
 => [10/23] RUN pip install pandas                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             6.4s
 => [11/23] RUN pip install Pillow                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.7s
 => [12/23] RUN pip install scipy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              8.5s
 => [13/23] RUN pip install wandb --user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       8.7s
 => [14/23] RUN pip install PyYAML==5.4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.8s
 => [15/23] RUN pip install addict                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.1s
 => [16/23] RUN pip install future                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2.4s
 => [17/23] RUN pip install lmdb                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.5s
 => [18/23] RUN pip install requests                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.8s
 => [19/23] RUN pip install scikit-image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       9.8s
 => [20/23] RUN pip install tb-nightly                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9.2s
 => [21/23] RUN pip install tqdm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.6s
 => [22/23] RUN pip install yapf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.4s
 => [23/23] WORKDIR /home/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        10.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       10.3s
 => => writing image sha256:0e27f2b231818e7de8d86449df4354ec1b97d09fe5ebac5cbe01917576a4f908                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/so
```

I then went into the image and did:

```
(wandb-3.6) danielgoldstein@Daniels-MBP d % docker run -it so bash
root@e10afe4beed8:/home# python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 18:15:18)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>>
root@e10afe4beed8:/home# ls
root@e10afe4beed8:/home# pip freeze
absl-py==0.12.0
addict==2.4.0
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
configparser==5.0.2
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
docker-pycreds==0.4.0
future==0.18.2
gitdb==4.0.7
GitPython==3.1.14
google-auth==1.30.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
grpcio==1.37.1
idna==2.10
imageio==2.9.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
lmdb==1.2.1
Markdown==3.3.4
matplotlib==3.4.1
networkx==2.5.1
numpy==1.20.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.5.2.52
pandas==1.2.4
pathtools==0.1.2
Pillow==8.2.0
promise==2.3
protobuf==3.16.0
psutil==5.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyWavelets==1.1.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
scikit-image==0.18.1
scipy==1.6.3
sentry-sdk==1.1.0
shortuuid==1.0.1
six==1.16.0
smmap==4.0.0
subprocess32==3.5.4
tb-nightly==2.6.0a20210507
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tifffile==2021.4.8
torch==1.7.1+cu101
torchaudio==0.7.2
torchvision==0.8.2+cu101
tqdm==4.60.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
urllib3==1.26.4
wandb==0.10.30
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yapf==0.31.0
root@e10afe4beed8:/home# python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 18:15:18)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wandb
```

And everything worked fine. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I've been able to resolve the problem by using USER in the docker file. I was running this on a cluster so I think the problem was related to privileges. I added the following command: 
`ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID
RUN addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID user
USER user`